# Check if an Android app has been released: Jenkins does not make an app debuggable

Tags: android, debugging, jenkins

I've seen a lot of posts about that subject based on the `android:debuggable="true"` flag.

I guess this works fine but I have one particular case when using Jenkins building the app. Looks like it makes it not debuggable. My client is testing their staging server, but since we specify the end point url as production url when the app is not debuggable, they ended up testing their staging server with the production url.

So I guess a good way to solve it would just be to know in the code if the app has been published, i.e downloaded from the PlayStore.

Has anyone met this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could allow your application to look at an external storage location on your device and 
use the url in that file if found.

No file...normal processing
File found use that url.

This would allow you to point any application build (production or test) at any 
server url

Comment: The strategy that we use is a bit different, but in a way I ended up doing something like this. I don't like doing such things but I guess it works.